# Enabling font ligatures - why warning about JetBrains runtime

Tags: intellij-idea, webstorm

I get the following warning:

[image]

But [this page](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/IDEADEV/JetBrains+Runtime+Environment) says that all new versions of WebStorm run on WebStorm runtime already. Is it not true for my version?

```
WebStorm 2016.3.3 Build #WS-163.12024.17, built on January 31, 2017
Licensed to Maximus Koretskyi You have a perpetual fallback license
for this version Subscription is active until October 16, 2018 JRE:
1.8.0_73-b02 amd64 JVM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM by Oracle Corporation
```

Comment: 1) Check your environment settings -- it's possible that you have setup specific variable that tells JetBrains products to use that particular Java instead. 2) `Help | Find Action...` and look for `Switch IDE boot JDK...` action -- run it and choose appropriate option